# Cassandra giving TTransportException after some inserts/updates

Tags: nosql, cassandra

Around 15 processes were inserting/updating unique entries in Cassandra. Everything was working fine but after sometime I get this error. 
(When I restart the process everything is fine again till sometime)

> An attempt was made to connect to each of the servers twice, but none
>   of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was TTransportException:
>   Could not connect to 10.204.81.77:9160

I did CPU/Memory Analysis of all the Cassandra machines. CPU usage sometimes goes around 110% and Memory Usage was between 60% - 77%. Not sure if this might be the cause, as it was working fine with such memory and cpu usage most of the time.

p.s.: How to ensure Cassandra update/insertion works error free?

Comment: are u using pycassa? Also, you might wanna look into your system logs to see if there are any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra will throw an exception if anything goes wrong with your inserts; otherwise, you can assume it was error free.

Connection failures are a network problem, not a Cassandra problem.  Some places to start: is the Cassandra process still alive?  Does netstat show it still listening on 9160?  Can you connect to non-Cassandra services on that machine?  Is your server or router configured to firewall off frequent connection attempts?

Comment: It seems like may be Cassandra is crashing. Logs showing out of memory error. How to resolve this?